# compare checkin checkout dates with array blockdates

Tags: php, arrays, date

I'm building reservation web app.
I have array pulled from service, contains blocked dates.
using calendar widget I want to make reservation during 2014-07-30 until 2014-08-04.
since my reservation date is found in blocked dates (2nd index [2014-08-01 - 2014-08-02] is blocked then should return false (cannot continue reservation).

```
$checkin = '2014-07-30';
$checkout = '2014-08-04';

$blockedDates = array(
    array(
        'start' => '2014-07-24',
        'end' => '2014-07-27'
    ),
    array(
        'start' => '2014-08-01',
        'end' => '2014-08-02'
    ),
    array(
        'start' => '2014-08-12',
        'end' => '2014-08-15'
    )
);

function morfora($blokedDates, $checkin, $checkout)
{
    foreach ($blokedDates as $date) {
        if (($checkin >= $date['start'] && $checkin <= $date['end']) || ($checkout <= $date['start'] && $checkout >= $date['end'])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

var_dump(morfora($blokedDates, $checkin, $checkout)); //still true; should be false;
```

I need your help guys, thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

you have a mistake in "($checkin >= $date['start'] && $checkin <= $date['end']) || ($checkout <= $date['start'] && $checkout >= $date['end'])"
The conditional statement never formed,so always return true

Comment: yeah, I'm stuck on that. any idea?

Comment: if (($checkin >= $date['start'] && $checkin <= $date['end']) || ($checkout >= $date['start'] && $checkout <= $date['end'])){
            return false;
        }

Comment: i don't see the difference?
still got true. i think it's can not be solved with such simple comparison. >,,<

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function checkBookedDate($start_date, $end_date, $date_range)
{
    /**
     * @var $start_object DateTime
     */
    $start_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $start_date);
    $end_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $end_date);
    if (is_array($date_range)) {
        foreach ($date_range as $row) {
            $range_start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['start']);
            $range_end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['end']);
            if (($start_object > $range_start && $start_object < $range_end) ||
                    ($end_object > $range_start && $end_object < $range_end)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```